# Handling thread safe, shared values in memory using Rust

Tags: rust

## The Question

Are there any strategies/recommendations in Rust for how to handle rarely updated, shared, and mutable values?

## An Example

```rust
struct SharedMutableResource {
    some_value: String,

    // time at which value must be refreshed
    // probably daily or weekly
    expires_at: chrono::DateTime<chrono::Utc>, 
}

impl SharedMutableResource {
    pub fn get_some_value(&mut self) -> &str {
        if self.expires_at < Utc::now() {
            // some refresh method
            self.some_value = some_new_value;
        }

        self.some_value.as_str()
    }
}

struct AsyncRequiresResource {
    resource: Arc<SharedMutableResource>,
}

impl AsyncRequiresResource {
    pub fn borrow_resource(&self) -> Value {
        // is there any way to avoid borrowing as mut here for every request
        let some_value = self.resource.get_mut().get_some_value();
        
        // do something with the value
    }
}
```

## Some Context

I am trying to create a rolling key rotation implementation for signing my JWTs, ideally rotating keys anywhere from daily to weekly. These requests will come asynchronously and need to access the key value for signing and verifying tokens. However, the keys will be rotated based on a time constraint, so they could be updated at any request.

## The Problem

With thread safety in mind, right now I am trying to figure out the optimal way to handle accessing the key. Ideally, it would be stored in memory on the stack at runtime, as my understanding is that is the fastest retrieval method (most requests would require a JWT, and so I would like to ensure I avoid as many slowdowns during this process, like a connection to a db or IO ops). However, as this needs to be thread safe, I have two ideas but neither seem very good.

1. Use async arcs (Arc<Mutex> instead of Arc) 
   **Pros**

   - Thread safety is maintained
   - Very little modification to what I currently have

   **Cons**

   - Atomic operations for every single request
   - Basically all requests become syncronous as they wait in order for the lock so that the request can be processed.
2. Use an async thread (thread::spawn(task)) 
   **Pros**

   - Thread safety is maintained
   - Allows for better async handling of requests

   **Cons**

   - Seems wasteful to spawn an entire thread that will only run once a day/week to make one change

## A Summary

Basically, both ways seem pretty wasteful to me for a change that will only happen on a very rare basis. I wouldn't be worried about adding overhead to actually changing the value as it happens so infrequently, but in order to keep high read speeds within my (admittedly self imposed) constraints, I am havbing diffculty finding the path forwards. Are there any tools, strategies or some constraints I need to drop/have a misunderstanding of, in order to allow a infrequently mutable data, with fast read speed?

Comment: What do you currently have? It sounds like `RwLock` would probably be better than `Mutex` for your case. Why not put it in a `static`?

Comment: @PitaJ copying the key to a static would cause an occasional "half-wrong" keys due to copy operations not being atomic, wouldn't it?

Comment: No, a static `RwLock` would not allow that to happen.

Comment: What I suggest in my answer, `arc-swap`, is semantically equivalent to `RwLock<Arc>`, just faster.

Comment: @PitaJ oh, okay, i thought you suggested it as an alternative, not on top of RwLock.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I struggle to see why would would need an `Arc` in the `static RwLock` case, but `arc-swap` is probably still preferable as requests will never be blocked

Comment: @PitaJ It is not usually needed indeed, just a more direct replacement of `ArcSwap`. Although holding the lock just for the time period of cloning the `Arc` is faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is to use the [`arc-swap`](https://docs.rs/arc-swap) crate. It is intended exactly for this scenario: data that is commonly used but rarely updated. Loading the data is lock-free, and the crate is very commonly used (25M downloads as of time of writing on crates.io).

It provides various options, but the simplest is [`ArcSwap`](https://docs.rs/arc-swap/latest/arc_swap/type.ArcSwap.html).